# Почему путь из папок внутри архива создается такой длинный?

Tags: java, android, zip

Я создаю архив с помощью вот такого класса и когда я распоковываю его у него структура состоит из где то 10 папок(их названия повторяются цепочками из 4 - 5) и только в последней лежат файлы архива... Что я делаю не так?

```
public class ZipUtil implements Runnable {

private Context context;

public ZipUtil(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    File zipFile = getZipFile();
    ZipOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ZipOutputStream not opened!!!!!!!!!!!!!1");
    }

    try {
        //здесь мы отмечаем дирректорию которую мы хотим добавить в архив
        File dirToZip = ImageSaver.getAvatarPhotosDir();
        doZip(dirToZip, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private File getZipFile() {
    //здесь мы показываем где создать архив
    File dirForZip = ImageSaver.getAvatarPhotosDir().getParentFile();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    return new File(dirForZip + File.separator + "archive_" +
            timeStamp + ".zip");
}

private static void doZip(File dir, ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("ZIPing is started!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    for (File tmp : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (tmp.isDirectory())
            doZip(tmp, out);
        else {
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(tmp.getPath()));
            write(new FileInputStream(tmp), out);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("ZIPing finished!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}

private static void write(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    in.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле проблема была в том, что в функции doZip() в строке out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(tmp.getPath())); нужно указывать не tmp.getPath(), а tmp.getName(), так как path дублирует путь и код воспринимает это как создать все папки которые находятся по пути того файла который вы указываете... Наверное не совсем понятно объяснил, но в целом если у вас будет такая проблема, то попробуйте ее решить именно таким способом. Мне помогло.